# How to include <glib.h> in android cmake project

Tags: android, c, cmake, android-ndk

I have created an android project on windows with ndk template. I want to include ndk-build project into android studio. This ndk-build project is working fine separately when I run ndk-build command.

My requirement is to convert and use it in android studio so that I can debug the code on android mobile. At this time I am just using share library (so file) and call the required function from adb shell.

I have copied all the source files of my separate ndk project into my android studio project and also added them into native-lib(created by default by android studio) library. But, I am getting an exception on including glib.h.

I am not sure actually how to resolve it.

Please suggest something.

Comment: post your `CMakeList.txt` or `android.mk` and error logs please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:https://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-compiling.html

I usually use the following:[To complie]

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 dbus-glib-1` progname.c
```

Hope this will help you.